# PowerShell script that would display the security of SharePoint Site

Tags: permissions, powershell

I'm looking for a PowerShell script that would display or create a report of the security configuration of a site collection. Any help would be appreciated.

It would list:

- Site Collection Owners
- Each group and it’s owner
- Each group’s permission level
- Each permission level and which of the check boxes are checked.

Comment: I don't have an answer, however have a follow on question, if I have AD rights to admin the SharePoint but don't have remote desktop access, is there anyway to wrap this script to get it to ask me for permission and run it locally on my PC? If not I need to go to my network staff and get rights, I am just the application admin in this case... TIA -KJ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PowerShell is ideal for this.
You can use something like this get the information you want.

```
$siteUrl = "http://.." 
$site = Get-SPSite $siteUrl
$site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators
$site.RootWeb.SiteGroups | Select Name, Owner, Roles
$site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions | Select Name, BasePermissions
```

If you want to loop through all webapplication you could use code like

```
Get-SPWebApplication | Get-SPSite -Limit All | % {
    $site = $_
    $site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators
    $site.RootWeb.SiteGroups | Select Name, Owner, Roles
    $site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions | Select Name, BasePermissions
}
```

Comment: Thanks this does exactly what I need. Now is there any way to get it to export to any kind of file instead of you displaying it? @Remko

Comment: Never mind I was able to export it to a file, now just working on getting it display correctly. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Is there any to make this script pull the information for all site collections in a farm? I've tried to set it up but haven't had much luck. @Remko

Comment: Updated the answer how you can loop through all site collaections

Comment: One more thing. How can I get it to display the site collection url or Title? I posted the current code I'm using. @Remko

Comment: You can use $site.RootWeb.Url or $site.RootWeb.Title

Comment: That simple. I need to take some courses. Thanks @Remko