# Who has permission to see what?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server

We just encountered a problem in our site - 95% of the security permission settings that we had in place were lost.

We have added them back manually and suspect we have added them back 95% correctly but maybe we've forgotten some of them.

Is there a script we can run to see what the current security settings are? This will be a great future reference if the above ever happens again.

Ideally the script would include Sub-sites, doc libraries, web-parts, lists and which Groups or individuals have permissions to them. Also the level of permissions would be great to include e.g. Read, contribute etc.

I have lots of `slq` experience but do not know where to start with this script so cannot provide an initial attempt at the script.

Answer (score 0):

you can use powershell script which mentioned in [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77663/powershell-script-that-would-display-the-security-of-sharepoint-site) answer

```
$siteUrl = "http://.." 
$site = Get-SPSite $siteUrl
$site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators
$site.RootWeb.SiteGroups | Select Name, Owner, Roles
$site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions | Select Name, BasePermissions
```

Comment: thanks - do you know the answer to their follow up comment - is there a way these details can be pushed to a file?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176825.aspx

Comment: you can use  Write to a text file using  Write $site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions | Select Name, BasePermissions>>c:\logfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice sharepoint 2010 solution http://sushi.codeplex.com/releases/view/61586 with [security report](http://sushi.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Security%20Reports&referringTitle=Home)